# How to wrap text in line by adding spaces

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, wrap

I am writing one text which has some very long words but i don't need to split word in multiline using hyphen. I just want to add spaces to fit in the line as shown below.

```
       This is my first text for wrapping word
       in a file. This text need   to       be
       adjusted and acted based   on the table 
       which need to be  modified   and tested 
       basedonthethedata  which is given here.
```

How can i implement it?

Answer (score 7):

### Normal Length Words:

One way to do this is to use `\nohypens` from [the `hyphenat` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyphenat). Here is a comparison without (on the left) and with  `\nohypens` (on the right):

[image]

### Notes:

- If you wish to disable hyphenation for the entire document (not that I am recommending that), you can use

  ```
  \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
  ```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\newcommand{\Text}{%
       This is my first text for wrapping word
       in a file. This text need   to       be
       adjusted and acted based   on the table 
       which need to be  modified   and tested 
       basedonthethedata  which is given here.
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
\Text
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{2ex}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
\nohyphens{\Text}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

---

### Very Long Words:

If you have really long words, you need to specify where the breaks can occur in the word.
Below, I have used a solution from [How to break long word containing symbols but with no hyphen?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53965/how-to-break-long-word-containing-symbols-but-with-no-hyphen) to automatically add a possible break after every letter (the macro is not complete, but the code just needs to be duplicated for each letter/character after which you want to allow a break).

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forloop}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53965/how-to-break-long-word-containing-symbols-but-with-no-hyphen
\newsavebox\MyBreakChar%
\sbox\MyBreakChar{}% char to display the break after non char
\newsavebox\MySpaceBreakChar%
\sbox\MySpaceBreakChar{\hyp}% char to display the break after space
\makeatletter%
\newcommand*{\BreakableChar}[1][\MyBreakChar]{%
  \leavevmode%
  \prw@zbreak%
  \discretionary{\usebox#1}{}{}%
  \prw@zbreak%
}%
\makeatother

\newcounter{index}%
\newcommand{\AddBreakableChars}[1]{%
  \StrLen{#1 }[\stringLength]%
  \forloop[1]{index}{1}{\value{index}<\stringLength}{%
    \StrChar{#1}{\value{index}}[\currentLetter]%
    \IfStrEqCase{\currentLetter}{%
        % All the characters where you don't want hypen
        {a}{\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        {b}{\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        {c}{\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        {d}{\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        {e}{\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        {f}{\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        %  list other letters here.
        {z}{\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        % All the charactes where a break should have a hypen
        %{ }{\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MySpaceBreakChar]}%
    }[\currentLetter]%
  }%
}%



\newcommand{\Text}{\setlength\emergencystretch{.5\textwidth}%
    This is my first text for wrapping word
    in a file. This text need   to       be
    adjusted and acted based   on the table 
    \AddBreakableChars{Ultramicroscopicvolcanoconiosis},
    \AddBreakableChars{Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis}
    which need to be  modified   and tested 
    basedonthethedata  which is given here.\par
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
\Text
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{2ex}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
\nohyphens{\Text}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine but i don't want to use minipage as i have almost 100 sections in my report where i need to wrap text. Is there any way to use one global command for all the text in a report.

Comment: @user15662: You don't need to use a `mipipage`. That was just to show that the text wrapping worked by shortening the width of the page.

Comment: I mean to to say i don't want to repeat this command(\nohyphens) frequently. Is there any equivalent global command.

Comment: @user15662: Have already updated solution to show that.

Comment: i have one very long name in sentence but it goes out of margin.  "This text is having very lengthy word (Having all medical terms) like Ultramicroscopicvolcanoconiosis, Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis."   Ouput: http://postimage.org/image/iqtape4uf/6398e4be/

Comment: @user15662: Have updated solution.