# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) warning in footnote

Tags: footnotes

With this code:

```
Our baseline\footnote{The config can be found in the
published repository under the name
\begin{tiny}\texttt{dropout01.l2\_1e\_2.6l.n500.inpstddev3.fl2.max\_seqs100.grad\_noise03.nadam.lr05e\_3.nbm6.nbrl.grad\_clip\_inf.nbm3}\end{tiny}
.}
```

I get the warning `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)`.
I found many similar questions here with the same error message, which mostly suggest to add `\hfill` or something like that. But nothing like that worked for me to get rid of the warning.

What exactly is the problem? And how to I get rid of the warning?

Comment: LaTeX does not seem to know where to insert a linebreak in the repository name which results in the described warning. [How to break long word containing symbols but with no hyphen?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53965/134144) and [Allow line break, but without inserting a dash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26174/134144) might be of interest.

Comment: Adding `\raggedright` worked for me as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351647/225084

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `url` package for such objects, it knows how to break at a number of different characters already and you won't have to escape the underscores:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

Our baseline\footnote{The config can be found in the
published repository under the name
\url{dropout01.l2_1e_2.6l.n500.inpstddev3.fl2.max_seqs100.grad_noise03.nadam.lr05e_3.nbm6.nbrl.grad_clip_inf.nbm3}.}

\end{document}
```

Note `\begin{tiny}...\end{tiny}` is not defined by LaTeX, it is accident of LaTeX syntax that it works, the correct construct is `{\tiny ....}`.  On the other hand if you wish to style the output of `\url` then you should redefine `\UrlFont`

```
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\tiny\tt}
```

The above example then produces

[image: tiny samle]

which is too small to read comfortably.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comment by leandriis, by inserting `\allowbreak{}` in some places inside my `\texttt`, I solved this.