# How to wrap text in a table when there are no spaces at which to break the line?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I have a lot of text in table. I want to wrap it with in 2cm. 
In the last column, I have [1][2][3].....[89][100] but the column width is only 2 cm. 
It is supposed be wrapped by itself.

[image]

How can I implement that?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your table's setup. Have you tried `p{2cm}` as the specification of the final column?

Comment: I'd like the see a working example of the problem. I suspect that `p{<width>}` will not be enough because in the table shown there are no spaces in the content that would act as potential line breaks.

Comment: I am using p{2cm} but there is no space but still i need to wrap it. I just kept space [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] but still i canot wrap it. My Table definition is here cat("\\centering","\n")

cat("\\rowcolors{2}{rowcol}{white}","\n")
cat("\\begin{tabular}{>{\\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}>{\\arraybackslash}p{2.25 cm}>{\\arraybackslash}p{2.25cm}c>{\\arraybackslash}p{8cm}c>{\\arraybackslash}p{2cm}c}","\n")

Comment: @manish Please add info to the question (with proper formatting).

Comment: Above is sweave code. Below is latex code for table definition.  \rowcolors{2}{rowcol}{white} \begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}>{\arraybackslash}p{2.25 cm}>{\arraybackslash}p{2.25cm}c>{\arraybackslash}p{8cm}c>{\arraybackslash}p{2cm}‌ ​c}

Comment: @manish: Please edit such code directly into your question. It's better to have all the information in one spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think probably the brackets ought to be in math mode, and that gives the advantage of being able to use mathcode "8000 to insert an active definition for the closing bracket.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\edef\savedbrack{\mathchar\the\mathcode`\] }

\begingroup
\uccode`\~`\]
\uppercase{\endgroup
\def\breakablebracket{%
\mathcode`\]"8000
\def~{\savedbrack\penalty 50 }}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\breakablebracket$}p{2.0cm}<{$}|}
[1][7][3][8][5][9][7][8][9][89][100]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: table with wrapped contents]

Comment: Above solution works but i can not use alternate row color with P. Is there any way to use alternate color for table with wrap text using breakpoints.

Comment: \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=yellow,outerlinewidth=.5, innerleftmargin=10,innerrightmargin=10, innertopmargin=10,innerbottommargin=10]
\begin{tabular}{P{2.25 cm}P{2.25 cm}P{2.25 cm}P{7 cm}P{2.25 cm}} 
\rowcolors{3}{yellow}{white}
 col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5\\hline
GSTERR&GD234 &TAT & XYZ &[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15][16][17][18][19][20][21][22] 
\\ 
\hline 
GSWWQEE&RT1234 &AAC & ABC &[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15][16][17][18][19][20][21][22] 
\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}

Comment: In the above i am implementing alternate coloring with breakpoints but cannot do it. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: I can't see why row colouring and the breaking of text within the cell should interfere. You didn't include the code to show what package you are using but most of them seem to use my colortbl in the end to do the row colours and that should work for p columns.

Answer (score 13):

In this case, using the `p{2.0cm}` column type is necessary, but not sufficient as there is not a natural break point.  This is not related to being in a table, even in normal text, having using content such as `[1][1][3][2][5][3][7][8][9][89][100]` does not have a natural break point.

So, using just the `p{2.0cm}` column:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2.0cm}}
    [1][7][3][8][5][9][7][8][9][89][100]
\end{tabular}
```

produces:

[image]

---

### Manual Solution:

Here is a solution passing the contents to the ``\AddBreakableChars{}`macro, which allows for a discretionary line breaks following a`]`.  So with:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2.0cm}}
    \AddBreakableChars{[1][7][3][8][5][9][7][8][9][89][100]}
\end{tabular}
```

we obtain the desired result:

[image]

### References:

- This is adapted from [Automatic line breaking of long lines of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33572/4301)

---

### Automated Solution:

If you include the `\usepackage{collcell}` in the preamble, then you can define a new column type that automatically passes each entry in this column through the `\AddBreakableChars` macro via:

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\collectcell\AddBreakableChars}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}
```

and using a `P{<width>}` column type as in:

```
\begin{tabular}{P{2.0cm}}
    [1][10][3][11][5][12][7][8][9][89][100]
\end{tabular}
```

which yields the desired results as above.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newsavebox\MyBreakChar%
\sbox\MyBreakChar{}% char to display the break after non char
\newsavebox\MySpaceBreakChar%
\sbox\MySpaceBreakChar{-}% char to display the break after space
\makeatletter%
\newcommand*{\BreakableChar}[1][\MyBreakChar]{%
  \leavevmode%
  \prw@zbreak%
  \discretionary{\usebox#1}{}{}%
  \prw@zbreak%
}%

\newcounter{index}%
\newcommand{\AddBreakableChars}[1]{%
  \StrLen{#1 }[\stringLength]%
  \forloop[1]{index}{1}{\value{index}<\stringLength}{%
    \StrChar{#1}{\value{index}}[\currentLetter]%
    \IfStrEq{\currentLetter}{]}
        {\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        {\currentLetter}%
  }%
}%

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\collectcell\AddBreakableChars}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}


\begin{document}
\textbf{Manual Solution:}\par
\begin{tabular}{p{2.0cm}}
    \AddBreakableChars{[1][7][3][8][5][9][7][8][9][89][100]}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\textbf{Automatic Solution:}\par
\begin{tabular}{P{2.0cm}}
    [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][89][100]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code is also used in follow up question: [How to use alternate table coloring with wrapping column?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61630/how-to-use-alternate-table-coloring-with-wrapping-column).