# How to use alternate table coloring with wrapping column?

Tags: tables, color, wrap

I am working on table in which the last column is wrapped with a command `\Addbreakable`. I need to color alternate rows as well. But I can do either `\Addbrekable` or coloring alternate rows.

### Note:

- This is a follow up to [How to wrap text in a table when there are no spaces at which to break the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61208/how-to-wrap-text-in-a-table-when-there-are-no-spaces-at-which-to-break-the-line)

Below is my sample example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\newsavebox\MyBreakChar%
\sbox\MyBreakChar{}% char to display the break after non char
\newsavebox\MySpaceBreakChar%
\sbox\MySpaceBreakChar{-}% char to display the break after space
\makeatletter%
\newcommand*{\BreakableChar}[1][\MyBreakChar]{%
   \leavevmode%
   \prw@zbreak%
   \discretionary{\usebox#1}{}{}%
   \prw@zbreak%
   }%

   \newcounter{index}%
   \newcommand{\AddBreakableChars}[1]{%
   \StrLen{#1 }[\stringLength]%
   \forloop[1]{index}{1}{\value{index}<\stringLength}{%
   \StrChar{#1}{\value{index}}[\currentLetter]%
   \IfStrEq{\currentLetter}{]}
   {\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        {\currentLetter}%
    }%
  }%

  \begin{document}
  \textbf{Manual Solution:}
   \newline
  \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1,    linecolor=yellow,outerlinewidth=.5, innerleftmargin=8, innertopmargin=8,innerbottommargin=8, everyline = true]
   %\begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}>{\arraybackslash}p{8cm}c|>  {\arraybackslash}p{1cm}c|>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}c|>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}c|>{\arraybackslash}p{2cm}c} 

  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{6cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}} 
  \rowcolor{yellow}
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4 & Col5\\
    test & data & data & data &\AddBreakableChars{[1][7][3][8][5][9][7][8][9][89][100]}\\
    test & data & data & data &\AddBreakableChars{[1][7][3][8][5][9][7][8][9][89][100]}\\

   \end{tabular}
   \end{mdframed}
   \vspace{1mm} 
   \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1.0, rightmargin=1.0, linecolor=red,outerlinewidth=.5, innerleftmargin=8, innertopmargin=8,innerbottommargin=8] 

   \centering 
\rowcolors{2}{green}{white} 
\begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}>{\arraybackslash}p{2.25 cm}>{\arraybackslash}p{2.25cm}c>{\arraybackslash}p{8cm}c>{\arraybackslash}p{2cm}c} 
\rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{Col1} &\textbf{Col2} &\textbf{Col3} &\textbf{Col4} &\textbf{Col5}\\ 
\hline 
ERBB3  &  TT2292239&  TQWT  &  Grammar. a grammatical unit of one or more words that expresses an independent statement, question, request, command, exclamation, etc.  & \AddBreakableChars{[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14]} 
\\ 
  &  TT2296336&  CQWG  &  Grammar. a grammatical unit of one or more words that expresses an independent statement, question, request, command, exclamation, etc.  & \AddBreakableChars{[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14]} 
\\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{mdframed} 
\end{document}
```

Please help me out of this problem.  I have tried many methods but nothing seems to be working fine.

Comment: I just edited my post with more complete example.

Comment: That is not quite a minimal example. You should eliminate packages that are not required to reproduce this problem. Also do you need all those rows to reproduce the problem - wont 3-4 do?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have removed extra package and rows to make MWE.

Comment: Why is the `graphicx` package required?  Is `mdframed` required to reproduce the problem? Also your example does not compile: `\rowcolors` is undefined.

Comment: It is part of my program so i want to test table in mdframed. For rowcolor i just added \usepackage[table]{xcolor} but still same pblm.

Comment: Your revised code works if you move the `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` up to the top. If the problem can be reproduced without a package, that package should be removed in the MWE.

Comment: Thanks it works but in first table cell height is very small. i want to provide some width myself like i did in second table. But with second i cannot wrap last column.

Comment: I found solution. Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your last version was not working properly was that your table column specification were incorrect. Once you make the column `p{2.0cm}` things work just fine:

[image]

### Notes:

- I have reformatted the column specification which should make it easier to read. In your version you should notice that there are extra `c` column type specification.
- I also moved the loading of `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` so that there are no package option conflicts.
- Two `@{}` were to the table column specification in order to eliminate the additional column spacing before the first and after the last column.  This eliminates the `Overfull \hbox` warnings. You could actually just use a `l` for columns 1,2, and 3 which would produce a not so wide table.
- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to display the page margins.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{collcell}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\newsavebox\MyBreakChar%
\sbox\MyBreakChar{}% char to display the break after non char
\newsavebox\MySpaceBreakChar%
\sbox\MySpaceBreakChar{-}% char to display the break after space
\makeatletter%
\newcommand*{\BreakableChar}[1][\MyBreakChar]{%
   \leavevmode%
   \prw@zbreak%
   \discretionary{\usebox#1}{}{}%
   \prw@zbreak%
   }%

   \newcounter{index}%
   \newcommand{\AddBreakableChars}[1]{%
   \StrLen{#1 }[\stringLength]%
   \forloop[1]{index}{1}{\value{index}<\stringLength}{%
   \StrChar{#1}{\value{index}}[\currentLetter]%
   \IfStrEq{\currentLetter}{]}
   {\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        {\currentLetter}%
    }%
  }%

  \begin{document}
  \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1,    linecolor=yellow,outerlinewidth=.5, innerleftmargin=8, innertopmargin=8,innerbottommargin=8, everyline = true]
   %\begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}>{\arraybackslash}p{8cm}c|>  {\arraybackslash}p{1cm}c|>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}c|>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}c|>{\arraybackslash}p{2cm}c} 

  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{6cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}} 
  \rowcolor{yellow}
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4 & Col5\\
    test & data & data & data &\AddBreakableChars{[1][7][3][8][5][9][7][8][9][89][100]}\\
    test & data & data & data &\AddBreakableChars{[1][7][3][8][5][9][7][8][9][89][100]}\\

   \end{tabular}
   \end{mdframed}
   \vspace{1mm} 
   \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1.0, rightmargin=1.0, linecolor=red,outerlinewidth=.5, innerleftmargin=8, innertopmargin=8,innerbottommargin=8] 

   \centering 
\rowcolors{2}{green}{white} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}
    >{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}>{\arraybackslash}p{2.25 cm}
    >{\arraybackslash}p{2.25cm}
    >{\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
    >{\arraybackslash}p{8cm}
    >{\arraybackslash}p{2cm}@{}
    } 
\rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{Col1} &\textbf{Col2} &\textbf{Col3} &\textbf{Col4} &\textbf{Col5}\\ 
\hline 
ERBB3  &  TT2292239&  TQWT  &  Grammar. a grammatical unit of one or more words that expresses an independent statement, question, request, command, exclamation, etc.  & \AddBreakableChars{[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14]} 
\\ 
  &  TT2296336&  CQWG  &  Grammar. a grammatical unit of one or more words that expresses an independent statement, question, request, command, exclamation, etc.  & \AddBreakableChars{[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14]} 
\\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{mdframed} 
\end{document}
```