# Latex longtable coulumn width

Tags: longtable, width

I have started learning Latex and writing my thesis. I want to typeset a long table.

```
\begin{centering}
\begin{longtable}{p{3.5cm}p{10cm}}
AdsBot-Google&209.85.238.1,209.85.238.107,209.85.238.116,209.85.238.119,209.85.238.16,209.85.238.163,209.85.238.185,209.85.238.200,209.85.238.232,209.85.238.241,209.85.238.246,209.85.238.249,209.85.238.25,209.85.238.33,209.85.238.39,209.85.238.45,209.85.238.68,209.85.238.7,209.85.238.71,209.85.238.74,209.85.238.81,209.85.238.86,209.85.238.89,72.14.199.10,72.14.199.107,72.14.199.113,72.14.199.116,72.14.199.122,72.14.199.2,72.14.199.23,72.14.199.26,72.14.199.37,72.14.199.46,72.14.199.5,72.14.199.55,72.14.199.58,72.14.199.66,72.14.199.75,72.14.199.81,72.14.199.84,72.14.199.87,72.14.199.98\\
        AdsBot-Google-Mobile&209.85.238.206,209.85.238.232,209.85.238.241,209.85.238.68,209.85.238.86,72.14.199.100,72.14.199.115,72.14.199.122,72.14.199.23,72.14.199.26,72.14.199.46,72.14.199.5,72.14.199.81,72.14.199.84\\
        AhrefsBot/1.0&212.113.37.105,212.113.37.106,213.186.122.2\\
\end{longtable}
\end{centering}
```

But the last column width seems not to be working. I tested with small lengths and even it shows the table as in the image. What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I assume the right-hand column contains mostly IP addresses and that IP addresses shouldn't be broken up across lines. Is there a reason for not having spaces after the commas? Actually, could you just replace all commas with spaces?

Comment: The only way the column entries can properly break is if you introduce some spaces (say `209.85.238.1, 209.85.238.107, ...`).

Comment: @Werner : Thanks, yes it worked after replacing comma with spaces. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the typographic consequences of a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to manually add spaces in the text to define points where you can break lines you can adapt the solution from [How to wrap text in a table when there are no spaces at which to break the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61208/how-to-wrap-text-in-a-table-when-there-are-no-spaces-at-which-to-break-the-line/61213#61213) to define a comma as a breakable character:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newsavebox\MyBreakChar%
\sbox\MyBreakChar{}% char to display the break after non char
\newsavebox\MySpaceBreakChar%
\sbox\MySpaceBreakChar{-}% char to display the break after space
\makeatletter%
\newcommand*{\BreakableChar}[1][\MyBreakChar]{%
  \leavevmode%
  \prw@zbreak%
  \discretionary{\usebox#1}{}{}%
  \prw@zbreak%
}%

\newcounter{index}%
\newcommand{\AddBreakableChars}[1]{%
  \StrLen{#1 }[\stringLength]%
  \forloop[1]{index}{1}{\value{index}<\stringLength}{%
    \StrChar{#1}{\value{index}}[\currentLetter]%
    \IfStrEq{\currentLetter}{,}
        {\currentLetter\BreakableChar[\MyBreakChar]}%
        {\currentLetter}%
  }%
}%

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\collectcell\AddBreakableChars}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{3.5cm}P{8cm}@{}}
AdsBot-Google&209.85.238.1,209.85.238.107,209.85.238.116,209.85.238.119,209.85.238.16,209.85.238.163,209.85.238.185,209.85.238.200,209.85.238.232,209.85.238.241,209.85.238.246,209.85.238.249,209.85.238.25,209.85.238.33,209.85.238.39,209.85.238.45,209.85.238.68,209.85.238.7,209.85.238.71,209.85.238.74,209.85.238.81,209.85.238.86,209.85.238.89,72.14.199.10,72.14.199.107,72.14.199.113,72.14.199.116,72.14.199.122,72.14.199.2,72.14.199.23,72.14.199.26,72.14.199.37,72.14.199.46,72.14.199.5,72.14.199.55,72.14.199.58,72.14.199.66,72.14.199.75,72.14.199.81,72.14.199.84,72.14.199.87,72.14.199.98\\
        AdsBot-Google-Mobile&209.85.238.206,209.85.238.232,209.85.238.241,209.85.238.68,209.85.238.86,72.14.199.100,72.14.199.115,72.14.199.122,72.14.199.23,72.14.199.26,72.14.199.46,72.14.199.5,72.14.199.81,72.14.199.84\\
        AhrefsBot/1.0&212.113.37.105,212.113.37.106,213.186.122.2\\
\end{longtable}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: That prints a nice table. Thanks for introducing "showframe".