# Using LuaLaTeX + a custom font ... How to let (non-spaced) Chinese characters break across lines

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, luatex, luatexja

*This question has a follow-up question, namely: "[Change letter-spacing / tracking for punctuation marks (luatexja-fontspec)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394160/change-letter-spacing-tracking-for-punctuation-marks-luatexja-fontspec)".*

Imagine you are working in **LuaLaTeX**, and you want to use Chinese texts (often featuring long series of characters without spaces) to break across lines, so that the end-user can actually still read them. How would you do this?

According to [an answer to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224734/67761) the OP "[How to use Chinese with lualatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222980/how-to-use-chinese-with-lualatex)", one can simply use:

```
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
```

However. This seems to overrule the use of a user-specified font, as would normally be customized by:

`\setmainfont{`...`}`

So my question is, in **LuaLaTeX**, how to both be able to:

- specify a custom font for the whole document,
- let the Chinese text line-break so as to make it readable?

## MWE (to be compiled with *LuaLaTeX*)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=30pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{HanWangKaiMediumChuIn_wp010-08}

\begin{document}

勞碌奔波、勉強應付。《京本通俗小說．錯斬崔寧》：「光陰迅速，大娘子在家巴巴結結，將近一年，父親見他守不過，便叫家裡老王去接他來。」也作「巴巴急急」、「巴巴劫劫」、「波波劫劫」、「劫劫巴巴」、「劫劫波波」、「結結巴巴」。

\end{document}
```

---

- **Note:** This MWE uses a custom font, namely **HanWangKaiMediumChuIn_wp010-08.ttf**, so one needs to [to download it](https://sites.google.com/a/mhcs-nj.org/mhcs-language-department/zhuyin-font-download/HanWangKaiMediumChuIn_wp010-08.ttf?attredirects=0&d=1) and install it in case one wishes to use the same.

---

P.S.: According to [the *luatexja*-package documentation](http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/CTAN/macros/luatex/generic/luatexja/doc/luatexja-en.pdf), changing the default fonts should be possible (e.g. using `\def\ltj@stdmcfont{psft:`...`}`), but I have not been able to do so. Perhaps this option is restricted to fonts which are part of the *luatexja*-package?

---

P.P.S: `\usepackage{seqsplit}` (see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33528/67761) to the OP "[Automatic line breaking of long lines of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33526/automatic-line-breaking-of-long-lines-of-text)") also doesn't seem to work for Chinese text.

Comment: Please provide a compilable answer for potential answer writers to play with. Also, which non-default font would you like to use?

Comment: @Mico Let me make a MWE then. I would like to use the font **HanWangKaiMediumChuIn_wp010-08.ttf**, so one needs to [to download it](https://sites.google.com/a/mhcs-nj.org/mhcs-language-department/zhuyin-font-download/HanWangKaiMediumChuIn_wp010-08.ttf?attredirects=0&d=1) in case one wishes to use the same.

Comment: And, just for clarification: The title of your posting refers to Chinese characters, whereas the `luatexja` package is set to deal with Japanese text. Japanese texts, almost invariably, contain a mixture of kanjis (Chinese characters) and hiragana and katakana glyphs. Are you looking for a solution that deals exclusively with Chinese glyphs/characters, or will it be a mixture of kanji and kana glyphs?

Comment: My particular purpose is to come up with a solution for Chinese characters only. I have just mentioned the `luatexja` package as per the mentioned answer to another OP, in which it was (simplistically) argued that: "*the tools designed for Chinese and Japanese usually work the same.*"

Comment: @Mico Added a **MWE** now.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Since you mention the `luatexja-fontspec` package in your write-up, is there a reason for loading `fontspec` instead (and for not using `\setmainjfont`)? (See also page 11 of the package's user guide.)

Comment: @Mico If you find a way to use the font **HanWangKaiMediumChuIn_wp010-08** without loading `fontspec` then that's fine for me.

Comment: `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}\setmainjfont{Microsoft YaHei}` as suggested by @Mico works fine for me (at least I get line breaks, but I have no idea if they are sensible).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That works great. Thanks a lot. If you could provide an answer I will accept. If you use the font from the OP, you will notice that the tracking (inter-letter-spacing) needs to be enlarged. Only, I don't know how to do so. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your font. But with another one `\setmainjfont` works fine. The spacing between the glyph can be extended with `\ltjsetparameter{kanjiskip=...}` (see 4.2 kanjiskip and xkanjiskip in the documentation):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=30pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{Microsoft YaHei}

\begin{document}
勞碌奔波、勉強應付。《京本通俗小說．錯斬崔寧》：「光陰迅速，大娘子在家巴巴結結，將近一年，父親見他守不過，便叫家裡老王去接他來。」也作「巴巴急急」、「巴巴劫劫」、「波波劫劫」、「劫劫巴巴」、「劫劫波波」、「結結巴巴」。


\ltjsetparameter{kanjiskip=20pt}
勞碌奔波、勉強應付。《京本通俗小說．錯斬崔寧》：「光陰迅速，大娘子在家巴巴結結，將近一年，父親見他守不過，便叫家裡老王去接他來。」也作「巴巴急急」、「巴巴劫劫」、「波波劫劫」、「劫劫巴巴」、「劫劫波波」、「結結巴巴」。

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However, it does not increase the inter-spacing of punctuation marks. Any solution there? Perhaps I could make a manual list of the necessary punctuation marks and thus automatically increase the spacing around them?

Comment: Additionally, using your solution, the ability to switch fonts mid-document using `\newfontfamily\myfont{`...`}` seems to have been lost, but that is of course easily fixed by adding a **j** to end up with `\newjfontfamily\myfont{`...`}`.

Comment: But a big problem remains, which is the spacing around punctuation marks, which is currently unaffected by your change in tracking. One can clearly notice this by using a large value, e.g. `\ltjsetparameter{kanjiskip=100pt}`. I have asked [a follow-up question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394160/change-letter-spacing-tracking-for-punctuation-marks-luatexja-fontspec).