# Break long lines without exceeding page limits for any given font size (xelatex)

Tags: xetex, line-breaking

The following code block was retrieved from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33536). It shows how to break long lines (see code and screenshot below.)

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
\def\scanfunction#1{#1}
\let\tempa\@empty
\def\scan@letters#1#2{%
   \g@addto@macro{\tempa}{#1\hskip 0pt plus 1sp minus 1sp}%
   \ifx#2\@empty
     \else 
       \expandafter\scan@letters
   \fi
#2}

\def\scan#1{%
  \scan@letters #1\@empty
}
\scan{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\tempa

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I noticed that when using `showframe` from the `geometry` package, one the `a`'s exceeded the range limit (see code and image below.)

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
\def\scanfunction#1{#1}
\let\tempa\@empty
\def\scan@letters#1#2{%
   \g@addto@macro{\tempa}{#1\hskip 0pt plus 1sp minus 1sp}%
   \ifx#2\@empty
     \else 
       \expandafter\scan@letters
   \fi
#2}

\def\scan#1{%
  \scan@letters #1\@empty
}
\scan{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\tempa

\end{document}
```

[image]

I solved this issue by changing `1sp` to `3sp` (see code and screenshot below.)

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
\def\scanfunction#1{#1}
\let\tempa\@empty
\def\scan@letters#1#2{%
   \g@addto@macro{\tempa}{#1\hskip 0pt plus 3sp minus 3sp}%
   \ifx#2\@empty
     \else 
       \expandafter\scan@letters
   \fi
#2}

\def\scan#1{%
  \scan@letters #1\@empty
}
\scan{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\tempa

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this doesn't work when increasing the font size (see code and screenshot below.). The following document was compiled using `xelatex` to set the font size to `60pt`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
\def\scanfunction#1{#1}
\let\tempa\@empty
\def\scan@letters#1#2{%
   \g@addto@macro{\tempa}{#1\hskip 0pt plus 3sp minus 3sp}%
   \ifx#2\@empty
     \else 
       \expandafter\scan@letters
   \fi
#2}

\def\scan#1{%
  \scan@letters #1\@empty
}
\scan{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\tempa
\end{document}
```

[image]

The excess space increases as the font size increases (see code and screenshot below.) The following document was compiled using `xelatex` to set the font size to `100pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{100pt}{100pt}\selectfont
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
\def\scanfunction#1{#1}
\let\tempa\@empty
\def\scan@letters#1#2{%
   \g@addto@macro{\tempa}{#1\hskip 0pt plus 3sp minus 3sp}%
   \ifx#2\@empty
     \else 
       \expandafter\scan@letters
   \fi
#2}

\def\scan#1{%
  \scan@letters #1\@empty
}
\scan{CCCCCCCCCCCCCC}
\tempa
\end{document}
```

[image]

My question is: How to break long lines without exceeding page limits for any given font size when compiling using `xelatex`?

Answer (score 1):

As already [commented](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65346811#65346811) in chat it's simply a choice of how much letter spacing you are prepared to accept. In the limit, if you just have two letters 1/3 `\textwidth` wide and you still want to justify the string you need to replace `1sp` by `.333\textwidth` so `.333\testwidth` is technically the answer to your question, but it might not be the answer you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{220pt}{240pt}\selectfont
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
\def\scanfunction#1{#1}
\let\tempa\@empty
\def\scan@letters#1#2{%
   \g@addto@macro{\tempa}{#1\hskip 0pt plus .3\textwidth minus .3\textwidth}%
   \ifx#2\@empty
     \else 
       \expandafter\scan@letters
   \fi
#2}

\def\scan#1{%
  \scan@letters #1\@empty
}
\scan{MMMMMM}
\tempa
\end{document}
```

---

You might prefer to use a fixed 0pt skip just to add the breakpoints and then use `\raggedright` so lines are left short when needed rather than being justified by arbitrarily large letter spacing.