# Is there a LaTeX template for electronics data sheets?

Tags: templates

Many electronics data sheets appear in very similar formats.  E.g., [Analog Devices DAC data sheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9780_9781_9783.pdf) in PDF has a very common format.

Is there a LaTeX template for generating a document like the above?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Note that there seems to be a controversy what the term "template" means. Some people talk about a document class, some people about an example document. See [what, in the context of LaTeX, is the meaning of “template”?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2443/2975) In your case you might be happy with one of these two, right?

Comment: As electronic engineer I now a lot of data sheets and wondered also about how to do them in LaTeX. Many of them are however made with Framemaker (e.g. Texas Instruments) or even Word (e.g. Analog Devices). You could write a special class holding all the required macros etc. and provide a template document, but both will be very specific to the layout you want, i.e. would be very different for every company. The chances are slim that someone made a general class or template for this, because it's very difficult to keep it general but useful. There are some helpful packages which we could list.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, you are right in that I would be happy with something that makes document building easier.  I am a complete LaTeX noob and my only experience with it has been collaborating with others where I was told which lines to type my contribution between and someone else handled all the graphics.

Comment: I do appreciate the power of LaTeX and would like to take advantage of it before becoming fluent in it.  Electronics data/spec sheets do seem to be composed of a set of very common sections and if there was a way I could take advantage of a template/class/macro/etc. to compose a spec sheet, that would be great (and encourage the use of LaTeX for further documentation in my group).

Comment: This duplicate has a few answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615/where-can-i-find-a-datasheet-document-class-or-a-tutorial-on-how-to-create-one/570808#570808