# Is it feasible to using data binding within Latex?

Tags: latex-misc

A year ago, I worked for a company doing .NET to create a customer report. They use DevExpress to generate a report based on customers' requirements. However, I realized the way it works is just painful and very time-consuming, because everytime they changed the requirement, we have to change a layout a bit due the the font and text data. At that time, I knew nothing a Latex, but I always think there must be a way to work smarter.
Today, while playing with TikZ package, I realized that Latex is just like another programming language, it's super powerful and flexible in term of drawing figure, positioning text, etc... But I'm not sure if we can use a variable inside Latex or not, for example, if I created a layout, says:

```
x^2 + 2x = A
```

Then is it possible for `A` to be a `variable` so that every time I need to pull out a new data from Database, I can just fit them in that particular position. I've just learned Latex for couple months, so there are many things that are new to me. In advance, I apologize if my question sounds a little insane or nonsense. Lastly, thank you for your time reading.

Comment: You are looking for the concept of TeX macros. You should look for `\newcommand` in your favorite LaTeX manual/documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way in my opinion would be to use a `template.tex`:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\begin{document}
$x^2 + 2x = \A$
This is some other data: \B.
\end{document}
```

And to produce a little `document42.tex` file for every document you want to generate, like this:

```
\def\A{…}
\def\B{…}
\input{template}
```

just fill the `…` with appropriate data.

Comment: As Caramdir pointed out, use `\newcommand` instead of `\def` to achieve more than just simple substitutions.

Comment: And use `\input` instead of `\include` in this case.

Comment: [Indeed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Comment: And when you feel comfortable with that, proceed in the way of LaTeX;) - learn to write *packages* (see `clsguide.pdf` in your TeX distribution, and possibly these questions here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/reference-guide-to-begin-writing-a-class-and-or-a-package http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/make-your-own-sty-files); then you might want to master one (or more) of a few packages supporting the key-value input, etc...