# Single format, free (e.g. LPPL licenced), journal article documentclass with existing corresponding MS Word templates

Tags: document-classes

We are planning a new open access scientific journal. I need to write Author's Guide, and hence prepare journal template - format.

I want to have MS Word and Latex templates.

Even though I wrote numerous documents with Latex, it seems it will be really hard to prepare a document class as told in this site on other QAs. For the time being, I am OK with using an existing document class with a free license.

I want the format to be single column, like standard article class.

Do you know such a document class?
 - article suits, but I could not find a corresponding Word template.
 - amsart suits, but I could not find a corresponding Word template. 
 - ieeetran has both Word and Latex, but it has two columns. I can easily convert it to single column, but it does not look good when I do so, as it was prepared for double column viewing. And I am not a guy with good art eye. Additionally I do not know the license for their Word template.

Comment: Can't you just create a Word template corresponding to `article`?

Comment: Writing a basic document class isn't difficult. See [Creating new class file: Where to start?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101250/creating-new-class-file-where-to-start), for example. Make your own Word template, and make a class file that matches (mostly, it would be difficult to get a perfect correspondence between the two formats).

Comment: Could be a little more elaborate on the precise specifications on such templates. What should be the abilities of the class/word template

Comment: The word template should have right styles created. E.g. the author should select the Abstract style, and it should be styled correctly. Similarly, in the latex code the author should use the abstract environment, and the right styles must be applied after compiling. Some generic content to show the styles used visually must be there, too. Reading style instructions are boring. So, in both cases, the author should be able to modify some headings, and just start typing.

Comment: @ozi, the `TeX` side should be easy, but I am not MS Word user, so I have no idea, how this could be achieved on the `dark side` ;-)

Comment: I am kinda OK on the `dark side`. It is not so hard. But orchestrating both templates simultaneously is the hard part probably.

Comment: How about a collaboration, a TeX user (no, not me `;-)`) and a MS-Word expert

Comment: It would be nice.

Comment: Are there any news here?