# How make a class or package?

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing, examples

I want to make a class or package but i don't have example class or package 
Would you help me and give  a example document  (***.cls**) or package(**.*sty**) ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) See if this is useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials

Comment: And also [Reference guide to begin writing a class and/or a package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2416). Please take a look at these questions as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: How complicated are your needs?  If you have a *TeX system on your machine, there are thousands of examples.