# Use \newcommand with a variable inside a style file

Tags: macros, package-writing

I have the following code which I put inside the preamble of my LaTeX documents:

```
\newcommand{\modulecode}{SESG6025}
\newcommand{\lecturetitle}{Interpolation}
```

In this case, that means that when I'm writing my lecture notes I can just use `\modulecode` to refer to the module code. I'm trying to create a style file to use for my lecture notes, and want to have some way that I can define what the module code is (that is, some way of setting the variable) in each document, so that I can then refer to it as above using `\modulecode`.

I can't seem to find how to do this through Google, but I'm sure it must be a fairly simple request. Any ideas?

Comment: Basically it sounds like passing a parameter to the package. Did you have a look at some [package guide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials)?

Comment: I've had a look at that, but I'm not sure exactly what I need to look for. I could do this by passing a parameter to a package, but I can't see how to do that with passing strings rather than just options.

What I was actually thinking of was creating a command (using `\newcommand` possibly) in the style file that would allow me to do something like `\setmodulecode{COMP6023}` in my document. That would seem to me to be the easiest way - and I'd guess it is fairly simple. Is that so?

Comment: I thought of packages like `hyperref` and `fixme`, which support options of the form `key=value`.

Comment: That sounds good, as an alternative to the other answers presented. Is it fairly easy to do that?

Comment: I don't know. But it's a good question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do you mean something like this?

```
\newcommand\setmodulecode[1]{\def\modulecode{#1}}
\setmodulecode{COMP6023}
```

if you have it inside a style file then do something like

```
\newcommand\setmodulecode[1]{\def\@modulecode{#1}}
\setmodulecode{COMP6023}
```

to prevent overwriting by a user. Alternatively use `\setmodulecode{}` for the
first definition.

Comment: You were quicker. Just one thing: you wrote `\setmodulcode` instead of `\setmodulecode`.

Comment: Thanks - that works well :-)

The only problem I have is that I then want to use `\modulecode` in a bit of fancyhdr code as below. This code is inside my style file, but is failing - presumably because it can't see `\modulecode` at the time that it is run (as it is defined in the preamble of the document). Is there a way around this:

   \fancyhead{}
   \lhead{\modulecode}
   \rhead{\lecturetitle}

Comment: @robintw: make your definitions before you load fancyhdr. If it doesn't work create a minimal example.

Comment: As usual, in the process of making the minimal example I found the problem. Apologies - I really must do that before asking! Thanks for your help.