# DocumentClass Writing

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Style/class tutorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials)

I am a newbie at LaTeX. But I need start from my own text style in LaTeX. I want to setup page format, margins, paragraphs style, fonts, etc. Can you please give me a link to the guide or show me your simple class? I was searching through the internet and I have not found any good tutorials for beginners.

Comment: Before you starting to write your own document class you should learn the basics of LaTeX.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to write your own document class? It is probably sufficient to load a ready made one and use packages to tweak it. In any case, it's not a great idea to do this before you've had a reasonable amount of experience.

Comment: OK, Can I setup my own margins and fonts in document class article.?

Comment: @itun Yes you can. One way is to use the geometry package. There are also many other "article" type of classes provided by the various journals for example revtex4.

Comment: There are many packages out there. For margins, let's see the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. For fonts, you usually include a package specifically for a font you want to use.

Comment: I can see how to setup margins at Tobi's answer. What about my font, like Tahoma, Arial, or Times New Roman?

Comment: I recommend reading [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), or some other text listed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/4012

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at

- the [clsguide](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf) about macros for package/class writers, and how to setup own classes
- the [dtxtut](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/dtxtut/dtxtut.pdf) about how to pack your file as most package/class authors do
- the LaTeX Companion about writing own classes

Since you are a beginner it is maybe preferable to start with an easy `\input` file and not writing a class. Just create a file (e.g.) `header.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
% ...
```

and us it like

```
\input{header}
\begin{document}
   Hello World!
\end{document}
```

To make you file available for multiple project you can save it in the user `texmf` tree. To find the right path call `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` in your terminal. It is possible that you must create the path first. then store your `header.tex` at `<TEXMFHOME>/tex/latex/header.tex`

Comment: I don't see making `header.tex` as a good idea, because when you change this `header.tex` file, some of your documents might stop working. I believe that a copy-paste method is more proper here. (I mean, when you start a new document, you take the headers from the previous one and modify what has to be modified.)

Comment: That’s the same with an own (and even possible but seldom with a public) class …