# How to customize a document class?

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

In LaTeX, we modify a predefined `documentclass` to fit our need. I wonder how we can edit the original `documentclass` (e.g. article) to have our customized properties? I mean which file is responsible for the article `documentclass` and should be edited to be customized?

I've seen some customized templates (`.cls` files), but they are indeed `templates` NOT `class`, as they somehow use the original class by `\LoadClass`.

NOTE: The tag `documentclass-writing` was very useful for finding interesting questions/answers, but the case is not what I meant to customize an original class of LaTeX.

Comment: Would this answer your question? [Style/class tutorials](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528)

Comment: @ArTourter the main answer is based on `\LoadClass{article}`. Am I wrong or missed something?

Comment: `.cls` files are indeed class files, i.e. `article` is provided by `article.cls` and `\documentclass{foo}` always loads `foo.cls`. Never ever *edit* existing class or package files. It is a mess and even against the license. Instead make a copy (e.g. `myarticle.cls`) and modify that one.

Comment: There are no "templates" with LaTeX. A class can be based on another class (and modified classes should be most the time!) by loading the base class using `\LoadClass`. That's perfectly fine!

Comment: also in that same page there is an answer linking to the [cls guide](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf) that may be of some help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to confuse some things and terms here.

You should never edit existing class or package files, at least not without changing the file name. This is a major point of the [LPPL license](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/lppl-1-3c.html). If you want to customize a class rename it and make your changes there. Even better would be to load the existing class using `\LoadClass` or `\LoadClassWithOptions` and then (re-)define all macros and settings the way you want it.

Every class files is located in `<name>.cls` file, if it is an "original" class or a derived  class (i.e. based on another class). There are no "templates" in LaTeX. People keep using this expression and keep confusing it with class files.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the LPPL license doesn't prohibit changing a class/style keeping the same name. But this is discouraged by the community.

Comment: @egreg: Wasn't this part of the older versions but was changed to allow distributions like Debian to make minor changes to the code? I can remember that the Debian people didn't regarded the license as free enough because of that before.

Comment: @MartinScharrer My question was if this is possible. Regarding the terminology, I meant creating an independent class which does not rely on an available class (with `\LoadClass`). You idea for copying the class to a new independent one is practical enough!

Comment: @MartinScharrer Yes, the "change the name if you modify" clause was weakened to get LPPL recognized as a free license.

Comment: @Ali -- the downside to copying, renaming and modifying an existing `.cls` file is that when/if bugs are corrected in that file, these corrections will not be reflected in the modified file -- a maintenance nightmare.  using `\LoadClass` gives the advantage of someone else doing the maintenance, although of course it's necessary to understand the original `.cls` file in any event.