# Modify footer of first page in custom class

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, documentclass-writing

I know I can do

```
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

But I want my custom class that I am making (based on article) to do this for me. It already does `pagestyle{fancy}`, but I can't get it to change the first page.

I tried (adding this to `myclass.cls`)

```
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{fancy}}
```

but that didn't work.

I also tried redefining `\maketitle` and adding it at the end:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
    \begin{center}%
    \let \footnote \thanks
        {\LARGE \@title \par}%
        \vskip 1.5em%
        {\large
            \lineskip .5em%
            \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
                \@author
            \end{tabular}\par%
        }% 
        \vskip 1em%
        {\large \@date}%
    \end{center}%                                                                
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em%
    \thispagestyle{fancy} %%%%%%%%%%%%% HERE
}
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: I've added what I tried with `\maketitle` in the post. I copied the code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/844/8289, and found that it did not change the appearance so it must be right (but of course the line I added in didn't change anything either, when it should have).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It wouldn't matter adding `\thispagestyle{fancy}` at the end of `\@maketitle`, since `\maketitle` issues `\thispagestyle{plain}` *after* calling `\@maketitle`, overriding any styles you set within `\@maketitle`.

Add the following to your class, after loading [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and the definition of `\maketitle` (or loading `article`, if you're not defining `\maketitle` yourself):

```
\g@addto@macro{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}
```

This appends `\thispagestyle{fancy}` *after* `\maketitle`. And, since `article` doesn't issue a page break after `\maketitle`, you should still be on the same page, making the above additional valid.

Comment: Thank you :). And thanks for the explanation as well. I was wondering if there was a way to add to macros like that, I'm sure I'll find this useful in other places too.