# What is the purpose of putting \newenvironment, \newcounter in a document class?

Tags: environments, counters

In `exam.cls`, I saw the following codes which I don't understand how do they function in the document class (`exam`):

```
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{partno}
\newcounter{subpart}
\newcounter{subsubpart}
\newcounter{choice}

\newenvironment{questions}{%

\newcounter{choice}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\Alph{choice}}
\newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice.}

\newenvironment{choices}%
  {\list{\choicelabel}%
     {\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
       \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 2.5em}%
       \def\choice{%
         \item
       } % choice
       \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
       \topsep=0pt
       \partopsep=0pt
     }%
  }%
```

What are their purposes, especially the `\newenvironment{questions}` and `\newcounter{question}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  It eliminates having to use a separate `.sty` style file. See the comments at the end of [Create multiple choice command or environment within my own latex class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78623/create-multiple-choice-command-or-environment-within-my-own-latex-class/78624#78624).

Comment: Are you the same person as the one who posted the question I linked to?  The rep is different but the userid is similar?  If so, perhaps your accounts should be merged.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\newenvironment` is used to define a new environment. The syntax (without optional argument) is

```
\newenvironment{<name>}[<number of arguments>]
  {<begin definition>}
  {<end definition>}
```

where `<number of arguments>` is an integer number between zero and nine, inclusive. Inside `<begin definition>` one can access the mandatory arguments (if present) using `#1`, `#2`, up to `#<number of arguments>`; those arguments are not directly accessible in the `<end definition>` part in the same manner, but you can store them using, for example, macros in `<begin definition>` and then use the macros in the `<end definition>` part.

When an optional argument is used, the syantx is

```
\newenvironment{<name>}[<number of arguments>][<default>]
  {<begin definition>}
  {<end definition>}
```

In this case, the optional argument can be accessed using `#1` and the mandatory arguments, using `#2` up to `#<number of arguments>`; the optional argument has the default value specified by `<default>`.

`\newcounter` is the LaTeX command to define a new counter; the syntax is

```
\newcounter{<name>}[<old counter>]
```

This globally defines the counter `<name>` and initializes it to zero; if the name of an already existing counter (`<old counter>`) is specified in the optional argument, then the newly defined counter `<name>` is reset when `<old counter>` is incremented.

Associate commands are

```
\setcounter{<name>}{<value>}
```

to globally set the counter  to the value given by `<value>`.

```
\addtocounter{<name>}{<value>}
```

to globally increment the counter  by the value given by `<value>`.

```
\stepcounter{<name>}
```

to add one to the  counter.

```
\the<name>
```

the representation of the counter `<name>`; one can say, for example,

```
\renewcommand\the<name>{\arabic{<name>}}
```

to get a representation using Hindu-Arabic numerals, and analogously one could use `\Alph{<name>}` (for a representation using upper-cased alphabetic characters), `\alph{<name>}` (for a representation using lower-cased alphabetic characters), `\Roman{<name>}` (for a representation using upper-cased Roman numerals), and `\roman{<name>}` (for a representation using lower-cased Roman numerals).

As a little example, let's define an environment that writes its contents using indentation on both sides and with numbering; for this we can use the existing `quote` environment; we create a counter for the numbering; the `<begin part>` simply starts the `quote` environment, steps the newly define counter and typesets its value; the `<end part>` just ends the `quote` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcounter{myexa}
\newenvironment{myexample}
  {\begin{quote}\stepcounter{myexa}{\bfseries\themyexa.}~\ignorespaces}
  {\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myexample}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{myexample}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In your concrete example (which only shows part of the original definitions and has duplicate definitions (i.e., `\newcounter{choice}`) that will produce errors), a new environment called `questions` is defined; internally this environment uses a numbered `\list` that will produce the numbering using the newly defined `choice` counter.