# Understanding differences between newtheorem and newenvironment

Tags: environments, theorems

The difficulty that I am having is that I make a newtheorem:

```
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

It however seems to act nearly the same as with newenvironment:

```
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
```

so why would I use one over the other?

as far as the manipulating them goes, I find resources for `newtheorem` with all sorts of combinations of arguments i.e.:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
```

which looks similar to the `newenvironment` setup except that we have an [1] in front of [Definition] in `newenvironment` which I am guessing is taking in an argument and thus could be expanded to several.  Also there seems to be a bunch of stuff defined in the 3'rd item of newenvironment where - `\begin{trivlist}\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]{\end{trivlist}`
is defined. Are `newtheorem`s arguments already defined in the system or something and not expandable to multiple arguments - is that one of the differences?

Anyways I am just trying to figure out when to use `newtheorem` and when to use `newenvironment`

Comment: The first one gives you automatic numbering; the second one doesn't; the first one gives you italics for the body of the structure, the second one, doesn't. If, additionally, you are using the `amsthm` package, you have three predefined styles that can be easily applied to structures (using `\theoremstyle`) and additionally, you can use the powerful `\newtheoremstyle` to customize the structures defined using `\newtheorem`.

Comment: See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems for all the kinds of things you can do with `\newtheorem` - numbering, describing, labeling, ... . Use it instead of `\newevironment` when you need those features.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: a theorem is indeed a kind of environment.  the reason that `\newtheorem` exists is that mathematians write a lot of theorems, the format of theorems is well defined by tradition, and it would be silly for every mathematician to have to define his/her own environment for every new document.  besides, publishers of mathematics do like to have some control over the style of their publications, so a reliable package is desirable.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Make that an answer, please.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina An answer is needed.

Comment: @egreg I will provide one tomorrow.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Does one month count for “tomorrow”? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I've started to provide an answer; I'll be making  some additions.

Answer (score 6):

Although `\newtheorem` is, in fact, similar to `\newenvironment`, they are different: `\newtheorem` is specifically designed to define a particular kind of environment: theorem-like structures whereas `\newenvironment` allows you to define arbitrary environments.

A theorem-like structure is one that typically has a head (formed by a name and a number) and a body (the actual contents of the structure). Of course, you could define your theorem-like structures "from scratch" using `\newenvironment`, but `\newtheorem` makes a series of provisions so as to easily account for the different formatting elements which characterize such structures. For example, just by using

```
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
```

and then

```
\begin{theo}
Theorem text.
\end{theo}
```

you'll get a head with automatic numbering in bold-faced font and the body will be typeset using italics. Additionally, the environments defined using `\newtheorem` have an optional argument which allows you to specify a name (or an annotation) for your theorem. Take a look at the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
Theorem text.
\end{theo}

\begin{theo}[Fundamental theorem of algebra]
Theorem text.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's a number of packages extending the functionality of the kernel's `\newthereom` command; the most popular ones are:

- [`amsthm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm).
- [`ntheorem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem).
- [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools). (a front-end for the two packages mentioned above).

The answers to [Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5599/3954) show a nice comparison between those packages.

Regarding the syntactical aspects, in [`this answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155714/3954) to [Understanding the arguments in newtheorem e.g. \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155710/3954), **barbara beeton** has explained the syntax for `\newtheorem`;  a similar explanation can be found in [`this other answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64933/3954) to [Using \newtheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64931/3954); an explanation for the syntax for `\newenvironment` can be found in [`this answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78739/3954) to [What is the purpose of putting \newenvironment, \newcounter in a document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78729/3954).

Comment: There is a typo in the first line ;-) "x similar to x"

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've added a possible link to an answer giving the explanation.