# Set Theorem counter as subsection number + 0.1?

Tags: theorems, counters

How to adjust counters for so that theorem is subsection+0.1 and the subsection number adjusts itself after the theorem. For example in the code below
the output produces **1.1 subsection** followed by the **Theorem 1.1** (I want this to be Theorem 1.2) this is followed by **1.2 Another Subsection** (I want this to 1.3).

I have tried using `\addcounter` and `\setcounter` but it does not produce the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]


\begin{document}

\section{Test Section} some text
\subsection{subsection} blah
\begin{theorem}
    How to set the theorem counter to 1.2 instead of 1.1 as in the output.
\end{theorem}
\subsection{Another subsection} How to set this counter to 1.3


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If I understand your question correctly, you wish the theorem and subsection numbers to be in the same sequence.  With `amsthm`, this  can be done with `\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Theorem}`.  This is explained in answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155710) and the question it points to as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `theorem` counter to be an alias (or duplicate) for the `subsection` counter using the methods described in [Slave duplicate counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33898/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dupcntr}[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname c@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname c@#2\endcsname
}
\makeatother
\dupcntr{theorem}{subsection}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section} some text

\subsection{subsection} blah
\begin{theorem}
How to set the theorem counter to 1.2 instead of 1.1.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Another subsection} How to set this counter to 1.3

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You so much. This helped a lot.