# TeX counter shared with \newtheorem

Tags: newtheorem, renewcommand

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
%%%%%

\newtheorem{defi}{definition}[subsection]

\newtheorem{defis}{definition}[defi]
```

hi guys
the code above gives me this

```
 definition 1.1.1
balabalbal
 definitions 1.1.1.1
blablalbalbal
```

i want to  get

```
 definition 1.1.1
balabalbal
 definitions 1.1.2
blablalbalbal
```

Comment: The optional argument must be in a different place: `\newtheorem{defis}[defi]{Definitions}`

Comment: it solved thanks

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Understanding the arguments in newtheorem e.g. \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]]

Comment: @barbarabeeton The link seems not to be included of the duplicate.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Understanding the arguments in newtheorem e.g. \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155710)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per egreg's comment.

> The optional argument must be in a different place:
> `\newtheorem{defis}[defi]{Definitions}`.