# Command for an underlined text and boxed text

Tags: formatting

How can I create two commands for a question with an underlined text in it or box with text in it in a sentence.

This is a sample:

[image]

Using the commands for underline and box I can now write it this way:

```
\question What is the synonym of \underline{Fun}?
\question What is the antonym of \boxed{Old}?
```

Comment: Every LaTeX guide explains `\underline` and `\fbox`

Comment: Where’s the actual problem? Do you want a `\question` macro ([Where does that even come from?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) do underline/box its full content? If not, is `\question` related to the actual question? `\underline` and `\boxed` are math mode macros (the latter provided by `amsmath`). Have some ideas: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}\usepackage{amsmath}\begin{document}\uline{Fun} \fbox{Old} $\underline{\text{Fun}}$ $\boxed{\text{Fun}}$\end{document}`

Comment: Related: [Create multiple choice command or environment within my own latex class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78623/5764)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel:  `\question` command is given when you use `\documentclass{exam}` or `\question` is a macro in `exam` document class. This macro when used will give the text a numbering order.See in the image example above. What I want to have is a command wherein when used this could automatically underline the text in the argument. Or automatically output the text inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

All that you need are already supplied by egreg in his comment. **Fact**: *You don't need to define these commands anymore.*

You also mentioned the `\boxed` command. Incidentally, you don't have to define this too. This is already provided by the `amsmath` package. This works only inside math environments, though.

**A demonstration.**

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question What is the synonym of \underline{Fun}?
\question What is the antonym of \fbox{old}?
\question Can I use both \verb+\fbox{<>}+ and \verb+\boxed{<>}+ to box words? Perhaps $\boxed{4}$ or \fbox{$4$}?
\end{questions}
\begin{equation*}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

**The output**

[image]

You can look up most of these commands and many things else by reading [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort) or other LaTeX guides.