# Separating the preamble to another file

Tags: preamble

What is the best practice for separating the preamble to a dedicated file?

I've seen two variants:

1. A package: preamble.sty and `\usepackage{preamble}`
2. A .tex file: preamble.tex and `\input{preamble}`

Which one is to be preferred?

Comment: To be honest, the one that you like best :-) Either way is ok and good practice, though i prefer to write my own packages (with options and stuff). Having said that, if you want to implement any options, write a package :-)

Comment: I think the package version is logically more consistent, although in the absence of options the definition of `\usepackage` is more or less `\input{#1.sty}` so it doesn't make any difference in practice.

Comment: Definitely the separate .sty file option: In a style file that's loaded with a `\usepackage` statement, the `@` ("at") character is immediately of category "letter", which makes all those `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` statements unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My opinion mostly:

Preamble commands that add *functionality* to the document (e.g., defining macros) belong in a package (`.sty` file).

Preamble commands that define the *look* of the document (paper geometry, page headers, font selections), belong in a custom *document class* (`.cls` file).  You can use high-level LaTeX commands to derive a custom class from a standard-issue class, and pass options to it.

See [Style/class tutorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials) for examples of both.

---

**Update** 2022-03-27 User @tush asked for a reference.  The closest I could find is [LaTex2e for class and package writers](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/clsguide.pdf) by the LaTeX project team. They write:

> **2.3 Is it a class or a package?**
>
> The first thing to do when you want to put some new LaTeX commands in a file
> is to decide whether it should be a document class or a package. The rule of
> thumb is:
>
> > If the commands could be used with any document class, then make
> > them a package; and if not, then make them a class.
>
> There are two major types of class: those like `article`, `report` or `letter`,
> which are free-standing; and those which are extensions or variations of other
> classes—for example, the `proc` document class, which is built on the `article`
> document class.
> Thus, a company might have a local `ownlet` class for printing letters with
> their own headed note-paper. Such a class would build on top of the existing `letter` class but it cannot be used with any other document class, so we
> have `ownlet.cls` rather than `ownlet.sty`.
>
> The `graphics` package, in contrast, provides commands for including images
> into a LaTeX document. Since these commands can be used with any document
> class, we have `graphics.sty` rather than `graphics.cls`.

Commands that set the document's look like paper geometry, page headers, font selections, seem closer to the `ownlet` case than to the `graphics` case.  That's why I think they belong in a class rather than a package.

Comment: Is it ok to place .sty files in the local folder next to the .tex document (if it contains really document-specific code) or should .sty files always be in the appropriate TEXMFHOME subfolder?

Comment: @TimHoffmann: either are perfectly acceptable. But if you are putting auxiliary code in a package you will probably want to use it more than once. That suggests a central location.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Could you refer me to where it is said that the commands related to the _look_ of the document should be in a `.cls` file?

Comment: @tush Like I said at the beginning, it's my opinion so I don't know if these words are written elsewhere. But I added a reference which I think supports it.