# Are there any TeX/LaTeX schools, teaching/training programs, tests and/or competitions?

Tags: tex-core, programming, exam

Are there any TeX/LaTeX schools worldwide? Who teaches TeX and LaTeX programming? In its different levels? For end/ordinary users (like typists), for intermediate programmers (LaTeX macro writers), and for advanced programmers (Using TeX primitives)?

Running regular tests to issue certificates?

Holding regular competitions, (for fun maybe) like ACM/ICPC and IOI?

Isn't it cool? I think, it would be great for developing a better web space.
The output of these could gives us better programmer for typesetting needs (including but not limited to page-setting and web text display.)

Comment: I sometimes give entry level TeX-Workshops at the university I'm currently enrolled in. but I've never heard of coding competitions for LaTeX so far. sounds like a great idea though.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials for example

Comment: I teach workshops for beginner and intermediate users (postgrads mostly).

Comment: As it stands this feels far too broad to me: lots of places have LaTeX training, largely in-house, and this can't really be enumerated. Certainly there is no 'official' standard/accreditation if that is what you are after.

Comment: I myself teach an entry level LaTeX course for undergraduates and also for graduate students, almost every semester, at university.

Comment: @JosephWright Nowadays, there are many academic journals which need some technical person, in charge of style/format of their journal, and sometime handle unexpected errors and warning. So hiring accredited personnel is almost a worry!

Comment: I don't think the TeX world would take well to official accreditation - indeed, I'm not sure what that could mean in this context. I agree with @JosephWright - in its current form, the question seems too broad. It also seems potentially opinion-based: you think official tests & certificates would be cool; somebody else thinks that way madness lies. (I think it sounds pretty grim, personally, and not at all attractive.)

Comment: Since this question doesn't fit here, how about getting to the correct place of discussing that topic? http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/edutex

Comment: @cfr I was thinking of something like Microsoft Certified Professional (MCP) status. I'm not saying this is necessarily desirable or achievable, but it's not uncommon in the business world to have 'official' courses on a range of things. Think all of the 'continued professional development' stuff one sees around.

Comment: @JosephWright I know. But who is Microsoft here?