# Any reference and tutorial on writing .cls file class?

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing, optional-arguments, package-options, tutorials

I was trying to re-edit the report.cls file to adapt to our institution thesis presentation format. I was stuck at declaring and executing options,also with error flag on xcolor file execution. Having a typical structure for declaring options or a tutorial on writing cls class will be appreciated.
My project ran but after the options were commented.
Thanks

Comment: `texdoc clsguide` is part of the base distribution. But if you don't show what error you got hard to suggest anything

Comment: Thanks @David, with try to show that .

Comment: I actually found discussion about "modifying class package" and related tutorials here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528/style-class-tutorials  very informative and helpful. In my project, I am exploring the LaTeX2e kernel classes (article.cls, especiallly the report.cls.) and the kernel itself (latex.ltx). *Will post the error message pls.